# What does . mean in docker? Does it mean the current working directory of the image or the local machine?

Tags: docker

I am confused about whether `.` means that it's a shortened abbreviation of the current directory of the image or if it's the current working directory on the local machine. Or is it the same meaning of `.` in most console commands like essentially selecting all in the current directory.

```
COPY somecode.java .

#copy the rest of the code

COPY . .
```

The `.` also seems to mean find the docker file in the current directory.

```
docker build -t image-tag .
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The `.` simply means "current working directory"

## docker build

In the context of the `docker build` command, you are using it to signal that the build context for `docker build` is the current working directory. Like so:

```
docker build -t mytag:0.1 .
```

Let's say that you have this structure:

```
/home/me/myapp/
├── Dockerfile
├── theapp.py
```

And you invoke the `docker build` command from `/home/me/myapp` - you will pass the current working directory as the build context. This means that docker will see the following filestructure when building:

```
/
├── Dockerfile
├── theapp.py
```

## Dockerfile

In the context of a `Dockerfile`, it means that same. Both inside and outside the image.

Take this `COPY` instruction for example:

```
COPY . /app
```

Here the `.` means the current working directory, where the `docker build` command is executed. This will be relative the to build context that is passed to the `docker build` command.

For this `COPY` instruction:

```
COPY theapp.py .
```

It means, take the file `theapp.py` and copy it to the working directory of the docker image that is being built. This directory can be set at build time with the `WORKDIR` instruction, so that:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY theapp.py .
```

Would leave you with the file `/app/theapp.py` inside the resulting docker image.

Finally, this `COPY` instruction:

```
COPY . .
```

Means take everything from the working directory where the docker build command is issued, relative to the build context that is passed to it. And copy it to the current working directory of the docker image.

Comment: of the image? of the local machine?

Comment: I added some to the answer, to try to clear this up. Please ask if something is still not clear.

Comment: The . simply means "current working directory" -  This is the line I was looking for. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation! I was really confused about the dots in the commands and the Docketfile and there's nothing about it in the official documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this crystal clear explanation.

Answer (score 10):

I saw 3 `.` characters on your question, so let me expand one by one.

The first, as you imagine, the `.` character means the current directory.

## In your Dockerfile

```
COPY . .
```

The second dot represented the current location on your virtual machine. Whenever you run `cd` command in the Dockerfile. That may be easy to understand.

The first dot more unintelligible a little. The first dot character represented the current location on your host machine. The location you input after `docker build` command like that:"`docker build [options] <location>`".

## Docker build command

The dot character means the current directory whenever you call your `docker build` command. For example:

`[~]$ docker build .`

The dot character represented for default home directory of this user on your real machine.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context. In your `COPY somecode.java .` it's the image. In `COPY . .` it's both. The first dot is in the local machine and the second dot is the image.

In the `docker build` command, it tells Docker to take files for the newly built image from the working directory on your local machine.

As others said, it's basically just means "current working directory". But when building a Docker image, there are two of those. One in your local machine where you're building the image. The second one is the file system that's built in the image.

Answer (score 2):

.(dot) means current working directory.

Comment: on the image or the local machine?

Comment: The last .(dot) represent current working directory. But .(dot) with COPY will be local(source) and image (remote target)